# Using for loop to read data from adomd or ado.net Datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, adomd.net

I am executing a query (DAX or SQL) where I am using `top` clause. The query returns records based on the length used with the `top` clause.  I am using following code.

```
        AdomdConnection conn =  new AdomdConnection(connString) ;
        AdomdCommand command  =   new AdomdCommand(query, conn);
        connection.Open();
        var resultSet = command.ExecuteReader(); 
         while (resultSet.Read())
        {

        }
```

**Problem**: Assuming query will return 1000 records, based on user input (startingRecord = 500 and lastRecord = 600) I want to fetch record no 500 till 600 & return the same. Only way I know is to use a while loop and keep a `counter`, which gets increment after every iteration. Now when the counter is 500 I will store the data and continue the loop until record no 600 is fetched. After that I will break the while loop.

Is there any chance I use for loop to retrieve the data. This will allow me to initialize the for loop counter at 500 and I can stop the loop at 600.

**What will be the most optimal way to retrieve the records. Is there any way to use LINQ?**

Comment: Why are you not fetching records starts from 500 to 600 from db rather than loop and filtering the records.

Comment: `DataReader` doesn't have an indexing attribute so you are cannot use a `for` loop.

Comment: @SainPradeep: I am using DAX queries which have certain limitation when it comes to paging. There are work around available but they do not work so well. So we are trying this mechanism

Comment: No, there is no chance to use a for-loop in this case, your current approach with counter and breaking the while-loop is imho the only solution to solve this. Imho there is nothing bad with your approach if you are also taking care of database performance.

Comment: @Kr15 : Thanks !! this is reassuring :)